# Packaging web component made with lit-element using rollup, postcss and tailwind framework

Tags: typescript, rollupjs, postcss, tailwind-css, lit-element

I'm trying to package a working webcomponent written using `lit-element/lit-html` with `tailwind` framework using the `postcss` plugin of `rollup` packager.

In my `dist/` target folder after a `rollup` i found the correct compiled js and html, but not the css after postcss. I try many things without success ...

```
dist/index.js 
dist/index.html
dit/webcomponents-loader.js
```

Code is also available if you want to test : `https://gitlab.univ-rouen.fr/sreycoyrehourcq/web-components.git`

My `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require("tailwindcss"),
        require("postcss-import"),
    ]
}
```

Il also try without loading potcss.config.

My `rollup.config.js`

```
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import postcssImport from 'postcss-import';

import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import path from 'path'

const extensions = ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.mjs'];
const outputDir = './dist/';

export default {
    input: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        dir: outputDir,
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'esm',
    },
    plugins: [
        resolve({ extensions }),
        commonjs(),
        typescript(),
        copy({
            targets: [
                { src: './src/index.html', dest: outputDir },
                { src: './node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/', dest: outputDir },
                {
                    src: './node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js',
                    dest: outputDir
                }
            ]
        }),
        postcss({
            plugins: [
                postcssImport()
            ],
            config: {
                path: "./postcss.config.js",
            },
            extract: path.resolve('dist/main.css'),
            module: false
        })
    ]
}
```

I also try using this block :

```
postcss({
    config: false,
    plugins: [
        tailwind(),
        postcssImport()
    ],
    extract: true,
    module: false
}),
```

My `main.css` :

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

My `package.json` :

```
    {
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c rollup.config.js",
    "start:build": "yarn run build && es-dev-server --root-dir dist --app-index index.html --compatibility none --open"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^8.4.0",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.4.4",
    "rollup-plugin-html": "^0.2.1",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "es-dev-server": "^1.57.1",
    "lit-element": "^2.3.1",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-nested": "^4.2.3",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import `main.css` in `./src/index.ts` and run `yarn build`.

```
...
import "./checkable-elements";
import "./hover-target";

// import main.css
import "./main.css";
...
```

build result is below, generated `main.css`

```
$ tree dist/ -L 1
dist/
├── bundles
├── index.html
├── index.js
├── index.js.map
├── main.css
└── webcomponents-loader.js
```

Comment: wow, this is so easy, i don't understand why my other try-and-test don't work :( ... Thanks !